# A way to execute a block only when a unique phrase is input

Tags: ruby

For example I have two commands in a program:

```
elsif @@content.downcase.include? "!roll"
      randomRoll = rand(100)
      puts("You rolled a #{add_comma_to_numbers(randomRoll.to_s)} (1-100)")

elsif @@content.downcase.include? "!roll1m"
      randomRoll = rand(1000000)
      puts("You rolled a #{add_comma_to_numbers(randomRoll.to_s)} (1-1m)")
```

Because !roll1m has the same prefix as !roll, they both execute when !roll is input, which I only want the top one to execute. 
Perhaps there is another method to use besides include??

I have thought about just simply flipping the two, however that would just be a temporary fix. Any suggestions would help

Comment: Why not just compare them with `==` instead of `#include?`

Comment: Why would flipping the two be "just a temporary fix"? It is a solid principle to check keywords from longest to shortest to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: I'm more interested in how they got 2 branches in an `elsif` chain to execute: `if false; puts "1"; elsif true; puts "2"; elsif true; puts "3"; end` only executes the "2".

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows:

```
r = /!roll\b/
```

which reads, "match the string '!roll' followed by a word break".

```
'!roll'.match?(r)
  #=> true
'I am on a !roll today'.match?(r)
  #=> true
'!roll1m'.match?(r)
  #=> false
```

If, in addition, we wish to match, `"tootsie !roll"` but not `"tootsie!roll"`, we could use either of the following regular expressions:

```
r = /(?<=\A|\W)!roll\b/
r = /(?<!\w)!roll\b/
```

`(?<=\A|\W)`, a *positive lookbehind* (`(?<=...)`), requires the string `"!roll"` to be immediately preceded by the beginning of the string (`\A`) *or* (`|`) by a non-word character (`\W`).

`(?<!\w)`, a *negative lookbehind* (`(?<!...)`), requires the string `"!roll"` to *not* be immediately preceded a word character (`\w`).

`\b` requires that `'!roll'` be followed by a *word break*, meaning that `'!roll'` must be followed by a non-word character or be at the end of the string.

Both return the following:

```
"tootsie !roll".match?(r) #=> true
"tootsie!roll".match?(r)  #=> false
```

I initially expected I could use the regular expression

```
r = /\b!roll\b/
```

but as I was reminded in the comments, the word-break character, `\b`, requires there to be a word character on one side and not a word character on the other side. This includes a word character before and no characters after or a word character after and no characters before.<sup>1</sup>

For example,

```
r = /\b!roll\b/
"!roll".match?(r) 
  #=> false (\W ('!') after \b but no \w before '!')
"tootsie!roll".match(r)
  #=> true  (\w before \b, \W ('!') after \b)
"tootsie !roll".match(r)
  #=> false (\W before and after \b)
```

<sup>1. This is not made clear in the documentation for [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html) (v2.7.0), which states, "`\b` - Matches word boundaries when outside brackets; backspace (0x08) when inside brackets".</sup>

Comment: word boundaries (`\b`) are (to my understanding) usually treated as "word character [most often letter, number, underscore] on one side and a non-word character on the other side. Since an exclamation mark is not a letter, number, or underscore, I think ruby's regex engine is seeing two non-word characters next to each other and the boundary fails to match that (try it with `"a!roll".match?(/\b!roll\b/) #=> true`

Comment: if you wanted to match something at the beginning of the word, I think something like `(?:\A|\W)!roll\b` might be a good bet, but I'm kind of hit or miss when it comes to regex, still. definitely not a pro

Comment: @SimpleLime More precisely, `\b` says "a word character on one side, and NOT a word character on the other side (i.e. absence of word-character, not presence of non-word character)". `a` matches `/\ba/` because there is NOT a word character on the other side; if it required a NON-word character on the other side, it should fail.

Comment: I am reasonably sure there is no regexp dialect in common use where `!` has any meaning except the literal one (matching the character `!`), and negating `=` in lookarounds (`(?!...)`, `(?<!...)`, or `\@<!`. `\@!`).

Comment: ...@Amadan for clarifying that. I guess `'a!roll'.match?(/(?<!\w)!roll\b/) #=> false` is another option. I'll edit.

Comment: @Amadan, it was [this reference](https://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/wd/regexp.html) that confused me: "! - If an exclamation mark (!) occurs as the first character in a regular expression, all magic characters are treated as special characters." (though it also says, "A list of all special (or 'magical') characters is as follows...", suggesting special and magic characters are one and the same).

Comment: @CarySwoveland It is confusing indeed. Open Watcom v2? It is a regexp dialect I never ran into before — definitely not "common use". How did you even stumble onto it? :)

Comment: @Amadan, Google took me there.